# Can't use ngDialog due to TypeError: ngDialog.open is not a function at Scope.$scope.discountModalOpen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I can't seem to use ngDialog with angular. here is my code

**discountModal Function**

```
 $scope.discountModalOpen = function () {
  ngDialog.open({
      template: 'views/discountModal.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      scope: $scope
    });
  };
```

**Controller for discountModal**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myProductsCtrl', 
['$scope', '$stateParams', 'productService', '$modal','ngDialog', '$filter','$location',
function ($scope, $stateParams, productService, $modal, $filter,ngDialog, $location) {
 });
```

**app.js**

```
angular
.module('myApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch',
'restangular',
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap',
'angularMoment',
'timer',
'ngMessages',
'ngDialog'
])
```

I am still getting following error in my javascript console

TypeError: ngDialog.open is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.discountModalOpen (http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/myProductsCtrl.js:293:18)
    at fn (eval at  (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13231:15), :4:242)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:478:9
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15916:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16016:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement. (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:477:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4435:9)
    at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4121:28)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would venture to say the issue is that your injectables are in the wrong order:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myProductsCtrl', 
['$scope', '$stateParams', 'productService', '$modal','ngDialog', '$filter','$location',
function ($scope, $stateParams, productService, $modal, ngDialog, $filter, $location) {
 });
```

You had `ngDialog` being injected into `$filter` and visa versa.

Comment: Thanks for that Mike. Helped me!